# Java - Calling one method before another

Tags: java

Using class methods, I want to make sure that the `getAverage` method is always called before the `setAverage` method

If `setAverage` is called first, it should return an error.

I'm confused as to how to check if the set is called before the get.

Answer (score 1):

If getAverable returns a non primitive object, you can check if the value is null.

If you return primitive value, like integer, you can use a boolean to check if the setMethod was called.

```
class Name {
    int value;
    boolean isCalled;
    public int getValue() {
        if(isCalled == false) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else {
           return value;
        }
    }


    public void setValue(int value) {
        isCalled = true;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct Java support for doing this. Of course, you could implement directly in the methods some algorithm which memorize which method was executed in which order. Better way to do this is with Aspect-oriented programming.

The simplest way to do what you want is to write an Aspect which writes in a Boolean that getter was executed and allows execution of setter only in case where Boolean flag is true.

Of course, this is only a first step and would be very error prone. (Concurrency, Repetiton etc.)

(I have written such a framework during my master thesis. Of course, it was a bit more complex than just checking single sequential method invocations.)